# configure git so that "git pull" instead of "git pull origin master"?

Tags: git

Using `git pull` used to pull from the remote repository as expected - now, it's asking me to use `git pull origin master`. I don't quite understand the instructions it's giving me, saying I can add something to my configuration file:

```
[branch "master"]
remote = <nickname>
merge = <remote-ref>

[remote "<nickname>"]
url = <url>
fetch = <refspec>
```

Right now my configuration file looks like

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = |redacted|
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

So I'm guessing I need to add

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = ??
```

What does "merge" need as its argument? What's a remote-ref(erence?)? I tried looking at http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config but it seems to be more about the command itself.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm new to this, didn't realize I needed to accept answers. ): I've gone back and hit the check mark on the answers I liked - is that enough?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

try:

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Comment: "Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'refs/head/master'
from the remote, but no such ref was fetched." ): Is there some way to tell what valid refs there are?

Comment: @munchybunch: replace `head` by `heads`

Comment: I tried this option first but didn't enough for me. After this option I used `git checkout -to <branch_name>` and that everything is going swimmingly.

Comment: @Iver this is just the entry in the configuration file. The whole question assumes you carry out the rest of the actions (pulling pushing)

Answer (score 21):

It should be enough just to execute

```
git config branch.master.remote origin
```

Comment: That does not add the line about merge when I run it. I still get the warning when trying to pull. @Horia's answer works for me. Looks like you need to run: git config branch.master.merge refs/heads/master

Comment: git config branch.master.merge refs/heads/master

Answer (score 11):

Just do:

```
git branch --set-upstream master origin/master
```

Comment: This one is deprecated. this is the other way: `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master`

Answer (score 3):

An easy way is to use `git checkout -t` to have the tracking set up when you create the local branch.